# Setting a variable to a number based on derived table's result

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a derived table that is defined as:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers INNER JOIN
(
SELECT customers.customer_id, SUM(clothingitem.price) AS Total FROM `customerorderstoclothingitem`
INNER JOIN customerorders ON customerorderstoclothingitem.orderid = 
customerorders.orderid
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = customerorders.customerid
INNER JOIN clothingitem ON clothingitem.clothingItemID = 
customerorderstoclothingitem.clothingitemid
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
) dTable ON dTable.Total > 300 AND customers.customer_id = dTable.customer_id
```

I tried using the following query:

```
UPDATE customers SET customers.discount = 0.3
FROM customers INNER JOIN
(
SELECT customers.customer_id, SUM(clothingitem.price) AS Total FROM `customerorderstoclothingitem`
INNER JOIN customerorders ON customerorderstoclothingitem.orderid = customerorders.orderid
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = customerorders.customerid
INNER JOIN clothingitem ON clothingitem.clothingItemID = customerorderstoclothingitem.clothingitemid
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
) dTable ON dTable.Total > 300 AND customers.customer_id = dTable.customer_id
```

but I get an error that my syntax is wrong at line 2 meaning that for some reason, the JOIN is causing an error. I believe the error must stem from the update section as when I use select, no error is caused and it runs as expected.

Comment: Your update query does not make sense in MySQL, which does not support common table expressions.  If you have a derived table and want to update it, then do so directly.

Comment: I want to update the customer table based on the derived table. In normal language, it's like: If the cutomer_id exists in the derived table, set discount to 0.3

Answer (score 0):

You can directly join customer table with derived table as below:

```
UPDATE customers INNER JOIN (
  // Your SELECT query for derived table
) dTable ON customers.customer_id = dTable.dTable.customer_id
 SET customers.discount = 0.3
```